# Bad gateway error on target website configured using the "nginx-proxy" docker container

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, vps, ovh

I try to resolve a **502 gateway error** on my vps on `latex.comnmodel.org`, using the great `nginx-proxy` docker container. I'm lost in config, so i crosspost this problem as a question in [github](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/301), and here to find an help.

My `docker0` is `172.17.0.1`, and the `docker -ps` command return :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
dca0d15c69bf        sharelatex/sharelatex   "/sbin/my_init"          2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:5000->80/tcp                       sharelatex
55ebd6b84a6a        osixia/phpldapadmin     "/container/tool/run"    3 days ago          Up 3 days           80/tcp, 443/tcp                            sleepy_thompson
e8fe2bd50c3a        osixia/openldap         "/container/tool/run"    3 days ago          Up 3 days           389/tcp, 636/tcp                           dreamy_babbage
9597ef0cded5        jwilder/nginx-proxy     "/app/docker-entrypoi"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   pensive_raman
```

I create the sharelatex image with and without VIRTUAL_PORT option :

```
sudo docker run -d -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=latex.comnmodel.org" -e "VIRTUAL_PORT=80" -v ~/sharelatex_data:/var/lib/sharelatex -p 5000:80 --name=sharelatex sharelatex/sharelatex
```

The `docker exec pensive_raman grep -vE '^\s*$' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` return

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
upstream latex.comnmodel.org {
                        # sharelatex
                        server 172.17.0.5:80;
}
server {
        server_name latex.comnmodel.org;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://latex.comnmodel.org;
        }
}
upstream ldap.comnmodel.org {
                        # sleepy_thompson
                        server 172.17.0.4:80;
}
server {
        server_name ldap.comnmodel.org;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://ldap.comnmodel.org;
        }
}
```

When i `ping latex.comnmodel.org` located on my vps ip `51.255.47.40` :

```
PING latex.comnmodel.org (51.255.47.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 40.ip-51-255-47.eu (51.255.47.40): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from 40.ip-51-255-47.eu (51.255.47.40): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from 40.ip-51-255-47.eu (51.255.47.40): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=13.6 ms
```

The `docker logs pensive_raman` return

```
nginx.1    | latex.comnmodel.org 81.64.146.124 - - [22/Nov/2015:22:40:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 181 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
nginx.1    | latex.comnmodel.org 81.64.146.124 - - [22/Nov/2015:22:40:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 181 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
nginx.1    | latex.comnmodel.org 81.64.146.124 - - [22/Nov/2015:22:40:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 181 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
```

I try to connect to `pensive_raman` (the name of nginx-proxy image) and ping the sharelatex container `172.0.17.5`, without success, is there a problem with my network config ?

- Do I need to use the `--link` option of `docker run` to connect nginx-proxy container and sharelatex container ?
- I have two 80 port on `0.0.0.0`, it can be the problem, i need to precise an ip `172.17.0.5` when i run the sharelatex image ? This is not clean

The website `latex.comnmodel.org` return a `502 bad gateway`, what i miss here, this is very frustrating :(

**UPDATE 1 :**

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/) says that if `--icc = false`, the command `sudo iptables -L -n` command contain a DROP RULE. It seems this is not the case, so icc option take the default true value.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:80

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: If @mattias's provided answer doesn't resolve your issue, I suggest trying to rewriting your question to make what you're wanting more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running the docker daemon with `--icc=false` (inter-container communication)

Comment: I update my answer, it seems in my case icc value is default value equal to true.